# Remove padding on the sides of a GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-gridview

I have a GridView, like:

[image]

However, I need to remove the padding on the sides of the GridView to create more spacing between the items, so it looks more like:

[image]

How can I modify my GridView to reflect my needs?

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="24dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

Comment: Have you tried to play with `paddingRight` and `paddingLeft` ie(`android:paddingRight="-1dp"`)

Comment: It works, but two problems: 1) it feels hacky, 2) I don't know by how much the GridView is spaced on the sides.

Comment: It doesn't look how you expect?

Comment: do you have a custom view for the items?

Comment: @vspallas Yes, I do.

Comment: @vspallas I can assure you there are no extra margins.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your Layout margin in which your Gridview is contained.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what solved my problem:

```
 android:clipToPadding="false"
```